# How to use static_assert used with a member initilizer list

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, c++14, static-assert

I would want to use static_assert to enforce various limitations on configuration of my class. Earlier I would just use an enum and only allow a single constructor which requires said enum to enforce a limit on my class. This worked fine if I have something like below and the range is from 0 to 4, but once I have a range of 0 to 500 then using an enum becomes unwieldy.

Some_Class.h

```
class Some_Class {
    public:
        Some_Class(const unsigned int param);
    private:
        const unsigned int member_param;
};
```

Some_Class.cpp

```
Some_Class::Some_Class(const unsigned int param) : member_param(param) {
    static_assert(member_param < 500, "Param must be less than 500.");
};
```

Main.cpp

```
Some_Class foo4(125); // OK
Some_Class foo5(500); // Should fail at compile time.
```

This is what GCC throws at me when compiling with C++14:

```
1>  Some_Class.cpp: In constructor 'Some_Class::Some_Class(unsigned int)':
1>C:\some_path\Some_Class.cpp(3,2): error : non-constant condition for static assertion
1>    static_assert(member_param < 500, "Param must be less than 500.");
1>    ^
1>C:\some_path\Some_Class.cpp(3,2): error : use of 'this' in a constant expression
```

Comment: What if someone does `Some_Class foo6(getCurrentTimeInMilliseconds() % 1000);`?

Comment: Static asserts are performed at compile time. Function parameters are passed at runtime. I suggest a regular assert.

Comment: Ah, dang, I just realized. Is there any way to enforce a function parameter check for constructors at compile time, or does that actually just warrant a new question? Maybe throwing constexpr at this somehow might help.

Comment: @NeilKirk I am on a relatively minimal embedded system, so the ~4KB worth of code that assert adds even with optimizations is too much for my environment. I was hoping to use static_assert since based on my understanding it should introduce minimal if not zero extra code size.

Comment: What? Asserts are usually disabled in release builds. Where does 4kb come from?

Comment: You are right, but to actually use assert when debugging I still need to fit 4KB more worth of code on my device, and I only have less than 2 KB left worth of flash.

Comment: You can create your own assert macro that just calls abort.

Answer (score 2):

parameter value cannot be used in constexpr.

you have to turn in compile time value somehow:

- template your whole class:

  ```
  template<unsigned int size>
  class Some_Class {
      static_assert(size < 500, "Size should be less than 500");
  public:
      constexpr unsigned int member_param = size;
  };
  ```
- pass a integral_constant:

  ```
  template <unsigned int N>
  using uint_c = std::integral_constant<unsigned int, N>;

  class Some_Class {
  public:
      template<unsigned int size>
      Some_Class(uint_c<size>) : member_param(size)
      {
          static_assert(size < 500, "Size should be less than 500");
      }
  private:
      unsigned int member_param;
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want compile time check you should use templates:

```
template<int size>
class Some_Class {
public:
    Some_Class() : member_param(size) { static_assert(size < 500, "Size should be less than 500"); }
private:
    const unsigned int member_param;
}
```

Then using the class the user must specify the size explicitly:

```
void myFunction() {
    Some_Class<20> class20; // Works
    Some_Class<500> class500; // Compiler error
}
```

Edit: Based on the comment from @NeilKirk the following code will achive the same without having to make the whole class a template:

```
class Some_Class {
public:
    template<int size>
    static Some_Class* createClass() {
        static_assert(size < 500, "Size should be less than 500");
        return new Some_Class(size);
    }
private:
    Some_Class(int size) : member_param(size) { assert(size < 500); }
private:
    const unsigned int member_param;
};
```

What it does: The constructor takes in the size but is private. Thus the class must be created using the `createClass` static function that is a template and you can do a static_assert on the size.

To create an object:

```
Some_Class* class = Some_Class::createClass<20>();
```

The normal assert is added in the Constructor for in-case if someone derives from the class and make the constructor public.

Comment: Why not just make the constructor a template?

Comment: @NeilKirk That is an interesting idea, but after a quick google search and writing a bit of code I could not seem to make it work for the constructor to be a template. I am adding an alternative to my original answer based on your comment.